# User entered text during pre-build event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file, pre-build-event

I am executing a batch file as a pre-build event.  The batch file however is expecting user input to continue (i.e., "Type x to continue")

Is there a way to enter an 'x' followed by 'Enter' in the pre-build event so that the process continues.

Additionally, I have a second batch file that is run after the first.  Will the pre-build process wait for the first to complete or will it try to execute the second batch file immediately after calling the first?  If so can I add a wait or pause to the pre-build?

Comment: can you share code in batch file 1 , which becomes easy why it is waiting for a user input ? rather we can tweak that first to solve the issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the call function** with a new line and it will call the second batch file after the first batch file is called. [How to: Specify Build Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

```
 call C:\MyFile.bat
 call C:\MyFile2.bat
```

You can pipe in user input characters using the | syntax

**e.g.:**

x is sent to the batch file along with the enter key.

```
 call echo x|C:\MyFile.bat
```

**Note:** Pre-build events do not run if the project is up to date and no build is triggered

Comment: I think you should use the pipe like `echo x|call C:\MyFile.bat`, because the command line `call echo x|C:\MyFile.bat` calls the `echo` command instead of the batch file...

Comment: @aschipfl it is taking the output of echo x and using it as input for the bat file . You have to use the call function because it is being used in a pre build event. I think putting echo in front will cause it to not execute correctly . I could be wrong but I know it works with the call first. Remember it is being called from pre build event.